# Grails UrlMappings Spock Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I have a basic mapping defined in my UrlMappings.groovy If I run my app and go to /api/address/zip-code/12345 I get the show action to respond to the browsers request.

```
group("/api/address"){
    "/zip-code"( resources: 'zipCode', includes: ['show'] )
}
```

I am trying to create a test to validate that my mapping works because I am going to create a ton of mappings here and I want them to backed by a test. This is my test.

```
package com.vega.foo

import com.vega.foo.address.ZipCodeController
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings

@TestFor(UrlMappings)
@Mock(ZipCodeController)
class UrlMappingsSpec extends Specification {

    void "test zip code mapping"() {
        expect:
        assertForwardUrlMapping("/api/address/zip-code/12345", controller: 'zipCode', action: "show")
    }

}
```

When I try and run this test I get the following error.

> Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: BUG! exception in phase
>   'instruction selection' in source unit
>   'C:\websites********\test\unit\com\vega\foo\UrlMappingsSpec.groovy'
>   unexpected NullpointerException

This is about as basic of a URL Mappings test as you can write. What am I missing here?

Comment: Based on the url mapping, the test should have been `assertForwardUrlMapping("/api/address/zip-code", controller: 'zipCode', action: "show")` or the mapping should have been `group('/api/address'){ "/zip-code/$id"( resources: 'zipCode', includes: ['show'] ) }`

Comment: You actually don't need the $id. From the docs it will create the following and I am saying that all I want out of that is the show action. I can manually verify that this works by visiting the URLs.

        GET     /books             index
        GET     /books/${id}     show

Comment: Also the assertForwardUrlMapping() method isn't the problem. If I replace my test with expect: 1 == 1 I get the same problem. Something is wrong with the @TestFor(UrlMappings)

Comment: `UrlMappingsSpec` should be in the default package as mentioned [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingURLMappings). See the note section.

Comment: Nice call @dmahapatro but I am still receiving the same error. It's good to know that it belongs in the default package so thank you for that!

Comment: Create a quick dummy app and push it to github replicating the issue. It will be easy to debug.

Comment: I do not think you need this `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings` in the test.

Comment: @dmahapatro I posted a very simple example to github and it is having the same problem as my project. The project is here https://github.com/cfaddict/UrlMappingsDemo

Comment: Also tried this method with no luck. Guess I'm just gonna have to skip testing UrlMappings https://grails.org/version/Testing+URL+Mappings/6

Comment: [Create a JIRA defect](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS) and link the sample github project. I believe using a `group` and/or `resources` messes things up in `UrlMappingsUnitTestMixin`. Please add the defect do not leave it orphaned. :) Anybody from the core team or I can look at it.

Comment: Great idea @dmahapatro I will get on it. Thank you for walking through this with me.

Answer (score 0):

[PR. This is how I was able to pass unit spec.](https://github.com/cfaddict/UrlMappingsDemo/pull/1/files)

Changes are almost what I had in comments.

- Adding `$id` to url mapping.
- Remove `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappings` from test.
- Specifying the `controller` and the `action` explicitly in `UrlMapping`.

Comment: We don't want to create our mappings that way though. Using the resources way creates an action assigned to each verb (post/get/put/delete) and allows you to define which actions are allowed. I get that your way works I am just a little confused on why introducing resources doesn't work.

Comment: You also end up with a class thinking there is an error the whole time

http://goo.gl/eyp1VQ

Comment: Agree. Because the test has to refer `UrlMappings` from the default package. You can add `grails-app/conf` as a source dir in IntelliJ and see it makes a difference.